# Construct a minimum spanning tree covering a specific subset of the vertices

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected, positive-edge-weight graph *(V,E)* for which I want a minimum spanning tree covering a subset *k* of vertices *V* (the Steiner tree problem).

I'm not limiting the size of the spanning tree to *k* vertices; rather I know exactly *which* *k* vertices must be included in the MST.

Starting from the entire MST I could pare down edges/nodes until I get the smallest MST that contains all *k*.

I can use Prim's algorithm to get the entire MST, and start deleting edges/nodes while the MST of subset k is not destroyed; alternatively I can use Floyd-Warshall to get all-pairs shortest paths and somehow union the paths. Are there better ways to approach this?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but can't you just run your favorite MST algo on `(k,E)`?

Comment: Uhm, how is this different from removing the unwanted vertices and running Prim (or Kruskal) on the remaining ones?

Comment: i'd be thinking 'subgraphs' there

Comment: If I remove the unwanted vertices I might also lose intermediate edges that connect `k` vertices that are far apart. For example if I have: `k--o--o--o--k` where `o` represents an unnecessary vertex and `k` represents one I need, if I deleted the middle `o` there would be no way to construct the MST between my `k` vertices.

Comment: So you interested in the minimum spanning tree, which doesn't necessarily span all vertices, only the vertices in k?

Comment: Exactly. The MST that includes all of `k` at least, and then as little else as possible.

Comment: @Jasie: then you can't get a minimum spanning tree because the subgraph is not connected.

Comment: Hi could you solve your problem? If possible can you help with the pseudo code/code? I have similar problem but the graph is unweighted.

Comment: The question is unclear about whether *k* is a number or a set. Will you please clarify?

Comment: @ash, would you mind un-accepting my answer? As pointed out in the comments, the algorithm is faulty, and I'd like to delete it to avoid spreading misinformation.

Comment: @aioobe done -- I haven't looked at this in a while but do you know if any of the other answers are correct?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. :-/

Comment: You can solve this problem using the Steiner Graph implementation given in Networkx - https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.steinertree.steiner_tree.html `steiner_tree(G, terminal_nodes, weight='weight')` and some examples can be found in this thread
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307336/generating-steiner-tree-using-network-x-in-python

Answer (score 25):

There's a lot of confusion going on here. Based on what the OP says:

> I'm not limiting the size of the spanning tree to k vertices; rather I know exactly which *k* vertices must be included in the MST.

**This is the Steiner tree problem on graphs.** *This is not the k-MST problem.* The Steiner tree problem is defined as such:

> Given a weighted graph G = (V, E), a subset S ⊆ V of the vertices,
>   and a root r ∈ V , we want to find a minimum weight tree which connects all the vertices in S to
>   r. [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQP8U.png)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/adv-approx/lecture10.pdf)

As others have mentionned, this problem is NP-hard. Therefore, you can use an approximation algorithm.

**Early/Simple Approximation Algorithms**

Two famous methods are **Takahashi's method** and **Kruskal's method** (both of which have been extended/improved by Rayward-Smith):

- Takahashi H, Matsuyama A: An approximate solution for the Steiner problem in graphs. Math. Jap 1980, 24:573–577.
- Kruskal JB: On the Shortest Spanning Subtree of a Graph and the Traveling Salesman Problem. In Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Volume 7. ; 1956:48–50.
- Rayward-Smith VJ, Clare A: On finding Steiner vertices. Networks 1986, 16:283–294.

---

*Shortest path approximation by Takahashi (with modification by Rayward-Smith)*

[image]

---

*Kruskal's approximation algorithm (with modification by Rayward-Smith)*

[image]

---

**Modern/More Advanced Approximation Algorithms**

In biology, more recent approaches have treated the problem using the cavity method, which has led to a "modified belief propagation" method that has shown good accuracy on large data sets:

- Bayati, M., Borgs, C., Braunstein, A., Chayes, J., Ramezanpour, A., Zecchina, R.: Statistical mechanics of steiner trees. Phys. Rev. Lett. 101(3), 037208 (2008) 15.
- For an application: Steiner tree methods for optimal sub-network identification: an empirical study. BMC Bioinformatics. BMC Bioinformatics 2013 30;14:144. Epub 2013 Apr 30.

In the context of search engine problems, approaches have focused on efficiency for very large data sets that can be pre-processed to some degree.

- G. Bhalotia, A. Hulgeri, C. Nakhe, S. Chakrabarti, and S. Sudarshan. Keyword Searching and Browsing in Databases using BANKS. In ICDE, pages 431–440.
- G. Kasneci, M. Ramanath, M. Sozio, F. M. Suchanek, and G. Weikum. STAR: Steiner-tree approximation in relationship graphs. In ICDE’09, pages 868–879, 2009

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This post led me to a nice R implementation in the `SteinerNet` package

Answer (score 11):

The problem you stated is a famous NP-hard problem, called [Steiner tree in graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree). There are no known solutions in polynomial time and many believe no such solutions exist.

Comment: Actually, Steiner tree in graphs has a fixed set of *k* vertices as input, while the OP gives just the *k* and lets the algorithm find the set. This problem is called [*k*-MST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-minimum_spanning_tree) and is also NP-hard. See also [problems related to MST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Related_problems) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Palec Actually, that is wrong. "I'm not limiting the size of the spanning tree to k vertices; rather I know exactly which *k* vertices must be included in the MST." This problem _is_ the Steiner tree problem.

Comment: Also, -1 to @meh because the fact that the problem is NP-hard doesn't mean we can't get useful solutions with approximation algorithms. This answer does not help the OP in solving his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Run Prim's algorithm on the restricted graph (*k*, *E'*) where *E'* = {(*x*, *y*) ∈ *V* : *x* ∈ *k* and *y* ∈ *k*}). Constructing that graph takes O(|*E*|).

Comment: This might work alright some of the time, but it's not even guaranteed that the E' is connected -- and even if it is, it might be possible to save arbitrarily much distance by introducing a Steiner point (i.e., a vertex not in k).  (Less than "arbitrarily much" if the distances obey the Triangle Inequality, but nothing says they have to.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker interested in posting an alternative solution?

Comment: @user2398029: I upvoted meh's answer (and I don't know why "Bill the Lizard" deleted adi's much earlier answer saying mostly the same thing).  Basically this is an NP-hard problem to solve optimally; if you google "Steiner tree approximation" you can probably get some OK algorithms.

Comment: @user2398029: It might be helpful to look at chapter 3 of this link from adi's answer: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Vijay.Vazirani/book.pdf.  (I (re)post this here since I can see deleted posts, but I'm not sure what the rep cutoff is for that.)