# Minimum cost arborescence of a specific subset of vertices

Tags: search, graph, tree

I can use the Chu-Liu/Edmonds algorithm to get the minimum cost arborescence of a directed weighted graph. I want to apply this for **a pre-specified subset of *k* vertices**. (I know exactly which *k* vertices must be included in the the tree).

What are the steps required to apply the Chu-Liu/Edmonds algorithm?

Similar to [Construct a minimum spanning tree covering a specific subset of the vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685291/construct-a-minimum-spanning-tree-covering-a-specific-subset-of-the-vertices), but for directed graphs / minimum cost arborescence (vs. undirected graphs / minimum spanning tree).

Comment: It is not clear to me what is exactly the question. If you are looking for hints for an actual implementation have a look here: http://www.gutenberg.us/articles/chu%E2%80%93liu/edmonds_algorithm#Algorithm

Comment: I have the implementation. The question is how to run it on a graph containing N vertices, where only a subset k of the vertices needs to be included in the graph.