# Get subgraph of shortest path between n nodes

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph, ggraph

I have an unweighted graph and I want to get a subgraph that has just the nodes and edges that contain the shortest paths between n known nodes.  In this case 3 nodes (11, 29, & 13 are the names).

### Question

**How can I get a subgraph of shortest path between n nodes in R?**

### MWE

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

hs <- highschool[highschool$year == '1958',]
set.seed(11)
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(hs[sample.int(nrow(hs), 60),])


# plot using ggraph
ggraph(graph, layout = 'kk') + 
    geom_edge_fan() + 
    geom_node_text(aes(label = name))
```

[image]

### Desired Output

The desired output would be the following green subgraph (Or close, I'm eyeballing the graph above and visually picking out what would be the subgraph) ignoring/removing the other nodes and edges.

[image]

Comment: @Frank I edited and added a visual representation of the desired subgraph output

Comment: Oh ok. That looks like a somewhat complicated problem, not simply the union of pairwise shortest paths. I guess the answer will be something like: take the induced subgraph and then "prune" in some sense.

Comment: What I thought was an easy question is likely much more difficult than I thought: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773324/shortest-path-between-three-nodes-in-a-graph

Comment: I also came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7685291/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the optimal solution, you don't need node 41, you can go directly from node 33 to 36, which uses one less node and edge. On the other hand if you want the shortest path between the selected nodes, then it seems to be correct, but you missed the one from node 11 to 29.

Comment: @maraca That's right.  I gave the disclaimer  "Or close, I'm eyeballing the graph above and visually picking out what would be the subgraph"  But you are inded correct that 41 isn't needed.  Your suggestion would be the solution I'm after.

Comment: @TylerRinker What does it mean to find the shortest path between n nodes? You can only find the shortest path between two nodes.

Comment: @VineetJain My terminology is likely not correct but I think you can understand what I mean from the detailed question and picture of desired output.  I'm using path in a colloquial sense which may be what is confusing you.  Perhaps a better way to say it is that I want the shortest set of paths that connect all points.

Comment: @TylerRinker Does that mean that you are not taking shortest paths from a particular source node to other n-1 destination nodes?

Comment: This is the Steiner tree problem, and is np complete even for unweighted graphs

Comment: https://blog.ephorie.de/finding-the-shortest-path-with-dijkstras-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the shortest path between n nodes. Since the shortest path is defined only between two nodes.

I think you want shortest path from `1` node to other `n-1` node you can use
`get_all_shortest_paths(v, to=None, mode=ALL)`  from `igraph` library.

- v - the source for the calculated paths
- to - a vertex selector describing the destination for the
  calculated paths. This can be a single vertex ID, a list of vertex
  IDs, a single vertex name, a list of vertex names. None means all the vertices.
- mode - the directionality of the paths. IN means to calculate
  incoming paths, OUT mean to calculate outgoing paths, ALL means to calculate both ones.

Returns: all of the shortest path from the given node to every other reachable node in the graph in a list.
[get_all_shortest_paths](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#get_all_shortest_paths)

So, now you have to create a graph from a list of the shortest paths.

1. Initialize an empty graph then add all path to it from the list of
   the path
   [adding path in graph](http://igraph.org/r/doc/plus-.igraph.html)

   ***OR***
2. make a graph for every shortest path found and take graphs union.
   [union igraph](http://igraph.org/r/doc/union.igraph.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need a matrix of shortest paths to then create a sub-graph using a union of all edges belonging to those paths.

Let *key vertices* be those vertices between which your desired sub-graph appears. You say you have three such key vertices.

Consider that the shortest path between any `i` and `j` of them is `unlist(shortest_paths(g, i, j, mode="all", weights=NULL)$vpath)`. You'd want to list all i-j combinations (1-2, 1-3, 2-3 in your case) of your key-verticies, and then list all vertices that appear *on* the paths between them. Sometime, surely, the same vertices appear on the shortest paths of more than one of your ij-pairs (See [betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality)). Your desired subgraph should include only these vertices, which you can give to `induced_subgraph()`.

Then arises another interesting problem. Not all edges between your choosen vertices are part of your shortest paths. I'm not sure about what you desire in your sub-graph, but I assume that you only want vertices *and* edges that are part of shortest paths. The manual for `induced_subgraph()` says that `eids` can be provided to filter sub-graphs on edges too, but I didn't get that to work. Comments on that are welcome if anyone cracks it. To create a subgraph with only edges and vertices *actually* in your shortest path, some surplus edges must be deleted.

Below is an example where some key verticies are chosen at random, the surplus-edge problem of subgraphs is visualized, and a proper shortert-paths-only subgraph is generated:

[image]

```
library(igraph)
N <- 40 # Number of vertices in a random network
E <- 70 # Number of edges in a random network
K <- 5  # Number of KEY vertices between which we are to calculate the
        # shortest paths and extract a sub-graph.

# Make a random network
g <- erdos.renyi.game(N, E, type="gnm", directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
V(g)$label <- NA
V(g)$color <- "white"
V(g)$size <- 8
E(g)$color <- "gray"

# Choose some random verteces and mark them as KEY vertices
key_vertices <- sample(1:N, 5)
g <- g %>% set_vertex_attr("color", index=key_vertices, value="red")
g <- g %>% set_vertex_attr("size", index=key_vertices, value=12)

# Find shortest paths between two vertices in vector x:
get_path <- function(x){
  # Get atomic vector of two key verteces and return their shortest path as vector.
  i <- x[1]; j <- x[2]
  # Check distance to see if any verticy is outside component. No possible
  # connection will return infinate distance:
  if(distances(g,i,j) == Inf){
    path <- c()
  } else {
    path <- unlist(shortest_paths(g, i, j, mode="all", weights=NULL)$vpath)
  }
}

# List pairs of key vertices between which we need the shortest path
key_el <- expand.grid(key_vertices, key_vertices)
key_el <- key_el[key_el$Var1 != key_el$Var2,]

# Get all shortest paths between each pair of key_vertices:
paths <- apply(key_el, 1, get_path)

# These are the vertices BETWEEN key vertices - ON the shortest paths between them:
path_vertices <- setdiff(unique(unlist(paths)), key_vertices)
g <- g %>% set_vertex_attr("color", index=path_vertices, value="gray")


# Mark all edges of a shortest path
mark_edges <- function(path, edges=c()){
  # Get a vector of id:s of connected vertices, find edge-id:s of all edges between them.
  for(n in 1:(length(path)-1)){
    i <- path[n]
    j <- path[1+n]
    edge <- get.edge.ids(g, c(i,j), directed = TRUE, error=FALSE, multi=FALSE)
    edges <- c(edges, edge)
  }
  # Return all edges in this path
  (edges)
}

# Find all edges that are part of the shortest paths between key vertices
key_edges <- lapply(paths, function(x) if(length(x) > 1){mark_edges(x)})
key_edges <- unique(unlist(key_edges))
g <- g %>% set_edge_attr("color", index=key_edges, value="green")

# This now shoes the full graph and the sub-graph which will be created
plot(g)

# Create sub-graph:
sg_vertices <- sort(union(key_vertices, path_vertices))
unclean_sg <- induced_subgraph(g, sg_vertices)
# Note that it is essential to provide both a verticy AND an edge-index for the
# subgraph since edges between included vertices do not have to be part of the
# calculated shortest path. I never used it before, but eids=key_edges given
# to induced_subgraph() should work (even though it didn't for me just now).

# See the problem here:
plot(unclean_sg)

# Kill edges of the sub-graph that were not part of shortest paths of the mother
# graph:
sg <- delete.edges(unclean_sg, which(E(unclean_sg)$color=="gray"))

# Plot a comparison:
l <-layout.auto(g)
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(g, layout=l)
plot(unclean_sg, layout=l[sg_vertices,])  # cut l to keep same layout in subgraph
plot(sg, layout=l[sg_vertices,])          # cut l to keep same layout in subgraph
```